# Type class with default type parameter

Tags: scala, typeclass

I am trying to solve the expression problem using type classes. I based my work on the example found in a late book of 2013 [Scala in Action](https://the-eye.eu/public/Books/IT%20Various/scala_in_action.pdf).

```
object StuffingSystem {

    trait Stuffer[V, M, P] { def stuff(v: V, m: M, additionalparameters: List[P]): ... }

    case class Input(v: BigDecimal) {

        def stuff[M, P](m: M, additionalparameters: List[P])(implicit stuffer: Stuffer[Input, M, P]) = stuffer.stuff(v, m, additionalparameters)
    }
    case class Material(o: String)
}

object Stuffers {

import StuffingSystem._

implicit object InputStuffer extends Stuffer[Input, Material, Int] {

  def stuff(v: Input, m: Material, p: List[Int]) = {

    ...
  }
}

val stuffed = Input(BigDecimal(101.0)).stuff(Material("o"), List())
```

The fact is that my `stuff()` function could use some additional parameters with other `Stuffer`s. The result I'm trying to get is not to be forced to give an empty parameter when none is required as shown in the example above ; I'd like to be able to write:

```
val stuffed = Input(BigDecimal(101.0)).stuff(Material(""))
val stuffedWithSomething = Input(BigDecimal(101.0)).stuff(Material(""), List("a", "b"))
```

I'm looking for an elegant way to do this. I don't quite understand currying but feel like it'd part of the solution.

Is it possible to have default type parameter here? Or is there a better path?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. What is `Input`? Is it some case class? You defined case class `Material` twice. This is illegal. What page of *Scala in action* do you refer to?

Comment: Edited. I refer to page 250. Should be clearer now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use default parameter

```
  object StuffingSystem {

    trait Stuffer[V, M, P] {
      def stuff(v: V, m: M, additionalparameters: List[P]): Unit
    }

    object Stuffer {
      implicit def mkStuffer: Stuffer[Input, Material, String] = new Stuffer[Input, Material, String] {
        override def stuff(v: Input, m: Material, additionalparameters: List[String]): Unit = ???
      }
    }

    case class Input(v: BigDecimal) {

      def stuff[M, P](m: M, additionalparameters: List[P] = List())(implicit stuffer: Stuffer[Input, M, P]) =
        stuffer.stuff(Input(v), m, additionalparameters)

    }

    case class Material(o: String)

  }

  object Stuffers {

    import StuffingSystem._

    implicit object InputStuffer extends Stuffer[Input, Material, Int] {
      def stuff(v: Input, m: Material, p: List[Int]) = ???
    }

    val stuffed = Input(BigDecimal(101.0)).stuff(Material("o"), List())

    val stuffed1 = Input(BigDecimal(101.0)).stuff(Material(""))
    val stuffedWithSomething = Input(BigDecimal(101.0)).stuff(Material(""), List("a", "b"))
  }
```

or varargs

```
  object StuffingSystem {

    trait Stuffer[V, M, P] {
      def stuff(v: V, m: M, additionalparameters: P*): Unit
    }

    object Stuffer {
      implicit def mkStuffer: Stuffer[Input, Material, String] = new Stuffer[Input, Material, String] {
        override def stuff(v: Input, m: Material, additionalparameters: String*): Unit = ???
      }
    }

    case class Input(v: BigDecimal) {    
      def stuff[M, P](m: M, additionalparameters: P*)(implicit stuffer: Stuffer[Input, M, P]) =
        stuffer.stuff(Input(v), m, additionalparameters:_*)
    }

    case class Material(o: String)
  }

  object Stuffers {

    import StuffingSystem._

    implicit object InputStuffer extends Stuffer[Input, Material, Int] {
      def stuff(v: Input, m: Material, additionalparameters: Int*): Unit = ???
    }

    val stuffed = Input(BigDecimal(101.0)).stuff(Material("o"), Seq():_*)

    val stuffed1 = Input(BigDecimal(101.0)).stuff(Material(""))
    val stuffedWithSomething = Input(BigDecimal(101.0)).stuff(Material(""), Seq("a", "b"):_*)
    val stuffedWithSomething1 = Input(BigDecimal(101.0)).stuff(Material(""), "a", "b")
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For this you don't need default *type* parameters, just a normal default parameter:

```
def stuff[M, P](m: M, additionalparameters: List[P] = Nil)(implicit stuffer: Stuffer[Input, M, P]) = ...
```

Of course there is a problem if you have multiple `Stuffer`s with different `P`, but there already is in your original situation.

Comment: You mean the empty `List` does not allow the type inference? So I'd still need to specify type? That what I would like not to do.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to specify `P` _somewhere_, either as type parameter to `stuff` or as `List[P]()`. Type inference needs to be based on something.